# How to use two models in a single view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, model-view-controller

I am trying to use the variables created in two different models, within a single view. I am using the View Model method to do so. However in my view, the variables within the models are unrecognized, and throw the error;

" 'CategoryItemViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'result' and no accessible extension method 'result' accepting a first argument of type 'CategoryItemViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? "

Below you can see the code I have for the two original models;

Category Model:

```
public class Category
{
   public string result { get; set; }
   public char[] delimiterChar { get; set; }
   public Array userData { get; set; }
}
```

Item Model:

```
public class Item
{                      
   public Array userDataItems { get; set; }
}
```

Thirdly I have created a view model with the intention to link the above two models into one,

ViewModel:

```
public class CategoryItemViewModel
{
   public Item ItemList { get; set; }
   public Category CategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

And then lastly I have a single controller responsible for combining the necessary models as well as initializing and returning them to the View Model so that they can be used in the view:

```
public ActionResult GetCategoryItem()
{
   CategoryItemViewModel CIVM = new CategoryItemViewModel();
   CIVM.ItemList = GetItemModel();
   CIVM.CategoryList = GetCategoryModel();
   return View(CIVM);             
}

public Category GetCategoryModel()
{
   var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");
   Category cModel = new Category()
   {
     result = "",
     delimiterChar = new[] { ',' },
     userData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFile) //Category Text File
   };

   return cModel;
}

public Item GetItemModel()
{
   var dataFileItems = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");
   Item iModel = new Item()
   {
      userDataItems = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFileItems) //Items Text File
   };

   return iModel;
}
```

Note that I am using the namespaces as follows for my controller and view:

Controller Namespaces:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using u18043039_HW3.ViewModel;
using u18043039_HW3.Models;
```

View Namespaces:

```
@using u18043039_HW3.Models
@using u18043039_HW3.Controllers
@model u18043039_HW3.ViewModel.CategoryItemViewModel
```

Lastly, my view:

```
 @Model.result
        @if (Model.result == "")
        {
            int count = 0;

            foreach (String dataLine in Model.userData)
            {

                string countString = count.ToString();
                string target = "dataLine" + countString;
                string trigger = "#" + target;

                <p>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="@trigger" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                        @dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[0]
                    </a>

                    <button class="btn" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Items", "Items")'" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]"><i class="fas fa-plus secondaryPlusIcon" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]"><i class="far fa-edit secondaryEditIcon" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]"><i class="far fa-trash-alt secondaryDeleteIcon" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]"></i></button>
                </p>



                <div class="collapse" id="@target">
                    <div class="card card-body w-25 p-3 collapsible" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.delimiterChar)[1]">
                        <!-- Card Elements here -->
                    </div>
                </div>

                count++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your implementation?

Comment: Implementation as in my view? If so, i have updated the question. Hope this helps!

Comment: Variables within the view such as 'result' , 'userData', 'delimiterChar' and so forth throw the error mentioned within the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your View, Model represents CategoryItemViewModel, in order to go to result, you need to access CategoryList first.

So you should do `@Model.CategoryList.result`

Comment: Got it, LinkedListT mentions the same, however you were first haha. Thanks to you both. Got it all working now.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining your `@Model` incorrectly. Model represents `CategoryItemViewModel` which does not have a result property. You have to update `@Model` to `@Model.CategoryList.result`.

Personal preference, I would only use @Model to inject model and then specify property where needed. I.E.

```
@Model

Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CategoryList.result)
```

Comment: Thank you, i will definitely take your advice into consideration. Appreciate the help and time spent mate.

Answer (score 2):

Your model needs to be of type `CategoryItemViewModel`

```
@model CategoryItemViewModel
```

You then need to access the `result` property via the `CategoryList` variable within the view model, for example:

```
@Model.CategoryList.result
```